# Entity Framework Collation error when trying to Updating Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6

I've created a C# Windows Forms application that uses a SQL Server database. Now I am trying to get my application to work on another PC by using the ***Package Manager Console*** and then running the ***Update-Database*** command.

I am receiving an error as soon as I try to update on the new PC that says:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I've done all the exact same steps on how I install my application on another PC, and I had no problem at all. All worked well.

My installation of SQL and VS2012 on both PC's were exactly the same as well, I did not change any settings on any of the machines. Might there be something else to this problem that I am missing?

I've also checked for other solutions that people asked about, but I cant really figure out how to change the **collation** of my whole database, or at least one table at a time. Here is a good answer that someone posted, but I do not really understand it or how to implement it in my own database if my own database can't be created through the ***Update-Database*** command.

```
...WHERE 
    fieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = otherfieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Is there anyone that might have any ideas? 0_o

Comment: What are you doing in the update that leads to the error? (Or is it in the seed?)

Comment: @jjj Thank you for the comment! Yes it is in the seed when I try to create my database :)

Comment: @CareTaker22 See my answer on **[Cannot resolve the collation conflict between ... in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257465/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-altdiction-cp850-ci-as-and/36118648#36118648)**.