# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a piece of code in my stored procedure as below -

```
update tblexpwitretrocmdocs set sCheckedOut = A.sEditor, idone = 0 
from #tblDocs A
JOIN tblexpwitretrocmdocs B ON A.SID = B.SID
where A.iDocumentTypeId in (16,17,13,11)
and A.sid not in (select SID COLLATE SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS from tblexpwitdocumentgeneral)
```

I am getting the error "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation." for the first line of code.

The column - sCheckedOut in table - tblexpwitretrocmdocs has collation SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS. So to make the column - sEditor compatible to it, I defined the temp table as below -

```
CREATE TABLE #tblDocs(
iId INT IDENTITY (1,1),
SID NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS,
iDocumentTypeId INT,
sType NVARCHAR(200),
sEditor NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS 
)
```

Still I am getting the same error. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: The collation conflict likely comes from the `NOT IN` predicate. Try - `AND A.sid not in (select SID COLLATE SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS from tblexpwitdocumentgeneral)`

Comment: Thanks Gareth, this is working for the given code. But now I had to change the update query a bit and the error still persists. Can you let me know what else needs to changed. I have updated the code above.

Comment: The error is now coming from the JOIN predicate `JOIN tblexpwitretrocmdocs B ON A.SID = B.SID` ---- Again try --- `JOIN tblexpwitretrocmdocs B ON A.SID = B.SID COLLATE SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS` -- If you run this these queries in SSMS, and double click the error message it will actually take you to the offending line, you then just need to add an explicit collation to resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks Gareth! working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the collation conflict add *"COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT"* keywords around “=” operator as shown below:

```
UPDATE tblexpwitretrocmdocs SET sCheckedOut = A.sEditor, idone = 0 
FROM #tblDocs A
JOIN tblexpwitretrocmdocs B ON A.SID = B.SID
WHERE A.iDocumentTypeId in (16,17,13,11) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
AND A.sid COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT IN 
(SELECT SID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM tblexpwitdocumentgeneral)
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Specify `DATABASE_DEFAULT` for the collation of all temp table string columns to use the current database default collation:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblDocs(
    iId INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    SID NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
    iDocumentTypeId INT,
    sType NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
    sEditor NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
);
```

For columns that differ from the database default collation, specify the exact column collation instead of `DATABASE_DEFAULT`.

Comment: Dan, I tried this already and it was not working. May be because the default collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and here it is being compared with SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS. Thanks!