# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the UNION operation

Tags: sql, reporting-services, view, union, collation

I have to join 2 views and create table which populates dates from the view.

But I am getting this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the UNION
>   operation.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Destinations_1415_1516_Union]
AS
SELECT *
FROM
[dbo].[Destinations_1415] 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
[dbo].[Destinations_1516] 
GO
```

Please suggest how to resolve this

Comment: Find the column(s) where the collations are different between the tables. Add collate clause(s) to one of the select's to force the wanted collation. (If you do UNION ALL, you don't need to do this - because no duplicate elimination is done.)

Comment: Yes I have identified the column, Can you please let me know syntax for that. Thanks!

Comment: `select ..., thatcolumn collate wanted_collation, ...`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam Could you please have a look at my answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257465/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-altdiction-cp850-ci-as-and/36118648#36118648) page?

Answer (score 2):

Hi agreeing with what people above have said, if you do the following:

```
SELECT ColumnA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    ,ColumnB COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    --,... (rest of Columns)
FROM [dbo].[Destinations_1415] 
UNION 
SELECT ColumnA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    ,ColumnB COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    --,... (rest of Columns)
FROM [dbo].[Destinations_1516]
```

This should get rid of your problem, you just need to identify what column it is that has the collation error.

Comment: What does `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` do, exactly?