# While Inserting "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have got the following error message when running a stored procedure.

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Below is the Stored procedure definition:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insPrvReqBck]  

 @uid varchar(50),@sts varchar(20),@remark varchar(150),
 @regRcv varchar(10),@regFrm varchar(15),@prv varchar(50) 

 AS BEGIN   SET NOCOUNT ON;         

 declare @scp table (cp varchar(50));   
 declare @cpid varchar(50);

 Insert into @scp exec GETCPID @uid;    
 select @cpid=cp from @scp; 

 INSERT INTO [ProvisionalRequest]
            ([PrvNo]
            ,[CPID]
            ,[Status]
            ,[Remarks]
            ,[RegisFormReceived]
            ,[RegFormNo]
            ,[PrvReqDate])
      VALUES
            (@prv,@cpid,@sts,@remark,@regRcv,@regFrm,GETDATE());        

      END
```

The error occurs while inserting the data into the table. Can you please help me resolve this?

Comment: Have You tried defining the collation for both @cpid, and cp column in @scp?

Comment: All you need is to collate the columns... 

Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: How to collate the columns @Alex

Comment: @ShebgoudaPatil Could you please have a look at my answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257465/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-altdiction-cp850-ci-as-and/36118648#36118648) page?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to All. Got it.. I have added the collate in trigger..