# Does using COLLATE in a TSQL query make permanent changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a query to `JOIN` two columns from different tables in different databases (same server), however I am getting this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "A" and "B" in the equal to operation.

The error originates in the line of the query in which I'm making the comparison between the two tables.

I understand I can use `COLLATE` to make sure both compared values have the same collation, but I was wondering if this has any kind of permanent effect on those tables, as in a permanent collation change, given they are needed as they are for other applications.

Example:

```
SELECT t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.value3 
FROM db1.dbo.tbl1 AS t1
JOIN db2.dbo.tbl2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Nope. It'll change the collation, if it can, to do the equal to operation. It won't permanently change anything. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations

Comment: Can you show us the code example?

Comment: @whisk I added an example, but the query that I need is itself very generic.

Comment: @user1676874 See my answer on **[Cannot resolve the collation conflict between ... in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257465/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-altdiction-cp850-ci-as-and/36118648#36118648)**.

Answer (score 1):

Think of COLLATE like a "CAST"... it's just saying "interpret this string as this collation", so that you can make both collations the same, and do the proper compares.

From your example:

```
SELECT t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.value3 
  FROM db1.dbo.tbl1 AS t1
       INNER JOIN JOIN db2.dbo.tbl2 AS t2
       ON t1.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Here I just used "DATABASE_DEFAULT" as an example collation... use whichever collation you wish (and if you use the Collation of one of the columns, you only need ONE COLLATE statement... on the OTHER one).

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, let's first make sure we're on the same page. We'll start with a couple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1(someText varchar(20)); -- uses default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CREATE TABLE dbo.table2(someText varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_BIN);
```

someTxt on table1 uses my servers default collation (*SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_AS*). The same column on table2 uses *Latin1_General_BIN*.

This query with give me the error that you're seeing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 t1
JOIN dbo.table2 t2 
  ON t1.someText = t2.someText;
```

Error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 23
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

There are two common ways to use COLLATE to resolve this error:

**Option 1 - In your query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 t1
JOIN dbo.table2 t2 
  ON t1.someText = t2.someText collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;

-- OR:

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 t1
JOIN dbo.table2 t2 
  ON t1.someText = t2.someText collate Latin1_General_BIN;
```

**Option 2 - Alter the table definition** 
Here I'm going to use COLLATE to change the column on table1 to match the column on table2.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table1
ALTER column someText varchar(20) collate Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Now I don't have to define the collation in the query.

**Your question**

> I understand I can use COLLATE to make sure both compared values have
>   the same collation, but I was wondering if this has any kind of
>   permanent effect on those tables, as in a permanent collation change,
>   given they are needed as they are for other applications.

If you go with option 1 then the answer is **NO**; using COLLATE in this way has noes not alter the table in any way. If you go with option 2 then, **YES** -  the collation on the column will change permanently. The impact can be dramatic or there might be no impact at all (I don't know enough about your applications).