# Teamcity and SQL server - Collation conflict

Tags: sql-server, teamcity, collation, conflict, jetbrains-ide

I have an issue with Teamcity and SQL server.

When I installed the SQL server I used the default collation type which is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
And for TeamCity DB it has to be Latin1_General_CS_AS according to their [document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/setting-up-teamcity-with-ms-sql-server.html), so for that, I created a DB called "TeamCity" and set the collation to Latin1_General_CS_AS.
and while installing TeamCity and setting up the external database I connected it to that "TeamCity" DB that I created.

For the Teamcity project, I added only one Build Step (Just a simple step to get me started with TC):
Runner type: Visual Studio (sln) &
Targets: Clean, Build

And now when I try to run the project with Teamcity I get this error:

> Unexpected exception: SQL error when doing 'Executing  with
>   parameters: [1585662168832] caused SQL error: ' while performing SQL
>   query: select r.test_name_id, r.success_count, r.failure_count,
>   r.last_failure_time, r.build_type_id from test_failure_rate r join #TT{build_type$} tmp on r.build_type_id = tmp.build_type_id where (r.last_failure_time is null or r.last_failure_time > ?) order by
>   r.test_name_id: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CS_AS" in the equal
>   to operation.

Does the collation type for the server effect TeamCity DB regardless of what collation the DB is set to? and how can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is the `JOIN`. The tables have different collations. If this is a fresh installation of SQL Server, i suggest a reinstalling if I am honest, with the collation you need. You'll have an easier time than trying to change the server's collation.

Comment: And how would I change the settings and update the DB connection in Teamcity after that? @Larnu

Comment: You'd have to start again there too. This is why I said *if* this is a fresh installtion.

Comment: Thanks, Larnu
I installed a SQL server with collation "Latin1_General_CS_AS" and restored the old Teamcity DB used, after that, I changed the server name in <TeamCity Data Directory>/config/database.properties to the new server name without the need of reinstalling TC again

Comment: @HadeelSwedan See my answer on **[Cannot resolve the collation conflict between ... in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257465/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-altdiction-cp850-ci-as-and/36118648#36118648)**.